# Network access stalls for some time on centos7 + zfs + samba installation

Tags: linux, centos7, samba, zfs

I have storage server with CentOS7 with 4 HDDs running on raidz (Raid 5). I access the files on it via samba.

When I copy files from it or watch movies sometimes the reading from samba is blocked for 10 seconds and then continues. I have no idea how often it blocks, but it's about once every 5-10 minutes. It could be once every X MB of data read...

The same computer was running just fine on CentOS6 with software raid.

in /var/log/messages there is nothing around the time I accessed the files

ZFS Status (I've run scrub manually before and it didn't find any errors):

```
# zpool status -v
  pool: backup
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
        still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
        the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
        the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 2h45m with 0 errors on Sun Nov 12 08:15:09 2017
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        backup      ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sda6    ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb6    ONLINE       0     0     0
        cache
          sde3      ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: storage
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        storage     ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sda5    ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb5    ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc5    ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd5    ONLINE       0     0     0
        cache
          sde2      ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

in smbd.log I only see (I disabled wide links):

```
[2018/02/13 10:08:59.532259,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4485(widelinks_warning)
  Share 'storage' has wide links and unix extensions enabled. These parameters are incompatible. Wide links will be disabled for this share.
```

I noticed these messages in dmesg (might have nothing to do with the stalls):

```
[ 1247.680530] perf: interrupt took too long (2513 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79000
[ 1551.176577] perf: interrupt took too long (3145 > 3141), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63000
[ 5137.178646] perf: interrupt took too long (3970 > 3931), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[ 5231.736533] perf: interrupt took too long (4969 > 4962), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40000
[ 5824.261569] perf: interrupt took too long (6215 > 6211), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 32000
[ 7051.322619] perf: interrupt took too long (7783 > 7768), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
```

**Update**

Here is some smartctl info:

`/dev/sda`

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       528         -
```

`/dev/sdb`

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     39047         -
```

`/dev/sdc`

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     19547         -
```

`/dev/sdd`

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     22117         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4022         -
```

Overall health for all drives reads **"PASSED"**

**No entries in error log.**

Here are the smart attributes:

```
/dev/sda

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       8975
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       74
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       528
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       74
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       65
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   121   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

/dev/sdb 

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       3
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       8441
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       149
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   047   047   000    Old_age   Always       -       39048
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       147
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       63
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       86
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   120   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

/dev/sdc

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   171   171   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4416
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       130
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   074   074   000    Old_age   Always       -       19549
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       130
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       47
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       97
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   117   101   000    Old_age   Always       -       30
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3

/dev/sdd

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   172   172   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4366
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       149
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   070   070   000    Old_age   Always       -       22120
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       149
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       61
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       147
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   114   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

Comment: Run a SMART self test on all your disks. `for disk in /dev/sd?; do smartctl -t long $disk; done` and then wait for them to finish.

Comment: BTW, you should not create zpools using sd* device names. This is a recipe for data loss, as these names may change every reboot and cause ZFS to be unable to put the pool back together. Always use the unique names in `/dev/disk/by-id`, which do not change.